# Is it possible to simplify the given system of equations so that the coefficient matrix is of less dimension?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

If I have a system of $8$ linear equations for the $8$ variables $\{x_1 ,x_2 ,x_3 ,x_4 ,x_5 ,x_6 ,x_7 ,x_8\}$ and with the three parameters $\{a,b,c\}$ reals and $a>0$. I want to work on nontrivial solutions of the system, therefore, I need to compute the determinant of the coefficient matrix which is in this case $8\times8$.

**My questions:**
Is it possible to simplify this system of equations so that the coefficient matrix is of less dimension?

$$  x_3 +x_4 +e^{\frac{i a}{2}} (a-1)\;x_2  +x_4 \; a-x_3\;  a-x_1 \; e^{-\frac{1}{2} (i a)} (a+1)=0,  \\   x_3 +x_4 +a (x_3 +x_6 )-x_5 -x_6 -a (x_4 +x_5)=0,  $$

$$  x_5 (a-1)+x_4  (a-1) e^{-i (a+b)}-(a+1) \left(x_6 +x_3  \;e^{i (a-b)}\right)=0, \\x_1 +e^{-\frac{1}{2} i (a+2 b)} \left((a+1) \left(x_4 +x_2 \; e^{\frac{3 i a}{2}+i b}\right)-x_3 \; e^{2 i a} (a-1)\right)-x_1 \; a=0,  $$

$$  x_8 +x_7\;  e^{2 i a} (a+1)-x_8 \; a+x_1  (a-1) e^{\frac{3 i a}{2}+i b}-x_2  (a+1) e^{\frac{1}{2} i (a+2 b)}=0,\\ x_7 \; e^{2 i a} (a-1)-x_8  (a+1)+x_5 (a-1) \left(-e^{i (b+c)}\right)+x_6  (a+1) e^{i (2 a+b+c)}=0, $$
$$ x_7 +x_8 +x_8 \; a+x_6  (a-1) e^{i (a+c)}-x_7 \; a-x_5 (a+1) e^{-i (a-c)}=0,\\x_8  \;a+x_1  e^{\frac{i a}{2}} (a+1)-x_7 -x_8 -x_2 \; e^{-\frac{1}{2} (i a)} (a-1)-x_7\; a=0.$$